# touchesBegan at the ViewController

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to know which of the several controls contained in my ViewController's main view is affected by the present touch event?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the location of the touch to the frames of each of the subviews

Comment: You can use `hitTest` to make it even easier.